# Drush terminated abnormally

Tags: drush

Drush version 9.7.0 Drush Launch version 0.6.0 Drupal ver 8.7.3 Open social dist 5.5.

The error I get at the command line when running `drush topic` or `drush cr` or any Drush command:

> [warning] Drush command terminated abnormally. Check for an exit() in
>   your Drupal site.

I have tried reinstalling Drush, removing and reinstalling, clearing cache via the GUI, but nothing seems to help.

I don't know where to check for an "exit() in your Drupal site".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an IDE to open your site and search into all your files.

When you find one **exit()**, comment it and try to use Drush again. Do it until you find the exit() that block Drush.